# Initialize React Native portion of hybrid app with structured data

Tags: react-native

## Problem

I'm integrating React Native into an existing Android app (ie. making a hybrid app). I've created an Activity to host a React Native view. This works fine.

Now, I need to pass structured data from native into React Native. Represented as JSON, it looks something like this:

```
{
    "landscape": ["http://example.com/1.jpg", "http://example.com/2.jpg"],
    "portrait": ["http://example.com/3.jpg", "http://example.com/4.jpg"]
}
```

Given the context I describe how can I make this data available as props inside of the React Native app?

I see that this is an `initialProperties` argument available, but it seems to accept a Bundle, which as far as I can tell (Android newbie here) only accepts scalar values.

## One option I am considering

- Create JSON object in Java
- Convert to a string
- Add to `Bundle` and pass into `initialProperties`
- Ingest as JSON and deserialize in React Native app

... but this seems hackish and requires me to add special code for Android that was not required for iOS.

## Alternatives?

Is there a straightforward approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing an array of strings into the Bundle?

```
bundle.putStringArray("landscape",yourArrayOfStrings]);
```